# key-value of JSON object not stored in Azure App Config as expected when reading from App Config

Tags: json, azure, .net-6.0, azure-app-configuration

I'm developing an Azure Function which has to consume JSON as input and then trigger a hybrid CI/CD pipeline split between on-prem and Azure DevOps. To split configuration from code I intend to use an Azure App Configuration store to retrieve configuration settings that the Function will use to trigger the correct pipeline depending on JSON input. I'm completely new to App Config but have tried to investigate how to properly use it. However, I have stumbled into a perplexing issue and can't find an explanation for it. I apologize if I have missed something obvious out there.

For the purpose of this question I have abstracted away any business-related terminology.

Imagine I have a JSON object stored in a file `TestStructure.json` that looks like this:

```
{
    "TestStructure": {
        "Repository1": {
            "RepositoryName": "Repository1",
            "RepositoryUrl": "https://url.repository1.com/"
        },
        "Repository2": {
            "RepositoryName": "Repository2",
            "RepositoryUrl": "https://url.repository2.com/"
        },
        "Repository3": {
            "RepositoryName": "Repository3",
            "RepositoryUrl": "https://url.repository3.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

I store this in my App Config using the Azure CLI with the following command:

`az appconfig kv import -n <myAppConfigName> -s file --format json --path "C:\workspace\TestStructure.json" --content-type "application/json" --separator . --depth 2`

The command yields the following key-value pairings:

```
---------------- Key Values Preview ----------------

Adding:
{"key": "TestStructure.Repository1", "value": "{\"RepositoryName\": \"Repository1\", \"RepositoryUrl\": \"https://url.repository1.com/\"}"}
{"key": "TestStructure.Repository2", "value": "{\"RepositoryName\": \"Repository2\", \"RepositoryUrl\": \"https://url.repository2.com/\"}"}
{"key": "TestStructure.Repository3", "value": "{\"RepositoryName\": \"Repository3\", \"RepositoryUrl\": \"https://url.repository3.com/\"}"}
```

These keys are what I expect to find in my App Config store.

Going to the App Config in the Azure Portal I find that the JSON object has been stored correctly, i.e. the keys are `TestStructure.Repository1`, `TestStructure.Repository2` and so forth, all with their corresponding values as the Azure CLI command reported back. This screenshot verifies it:

[image]

Now, to the actual problem. When I try to fetch a key from my App Config I get some weird behavior.

I have put together a simple Console App in .NET 6 to test how to read from the App Config:

```
1 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
2
3 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
4    .AddAzureAppConfiguration("MyConnectionString")
5    .Build();
6
7 var repository = config["TestStructure.Repository1"] // Returns null
```

It doesn't make sense to me why line 7 returns null, so I attached a debugger to inspect the `ConfigurationRoot` object a bit further and found the following:

[image]

What is going on here? Inspecting the `config` object reveals that the actual keys to index with are stored as `TestStructure.Repository1:RepositoryName` and not `TestStructure.Repository1` and then the corresponding values.

Thank you for taking your time to read my question. I hope I have expressed clearly what I am trying to achieve and what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of `TestStructure.Repository1` to be the whole JSON string, you shouldn't specify the `application/json` content-type when importing them. It's then your responsibility to parse the JSON string when you consume them in your app.

When a key-value is specified with `application/json` content-type, the App Configuration provider library will parse the JSON string and create **separate** configuration entries for each leaf node of the JSON object. That's the same structure as if you load them with a JSON file configuration provider. What you observed is expected. It's quite similar to the example documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-leverage-json-content-type#consuming-json-key-values-in-applications.